# Get model from repository without having to specify type through angle brackets

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a repository that contains many different models. When getting one of the models from the repository, I want typescript to know the type of the model without having to manually specify which type it is.

```
export class Repository {
    items = {};

    add<T>(name: string, item: T) {
        this.items[name] = item;
    }

    get(name: string) {
        return this.items[name];
    }
}

class BaseModel {
    insert() {}
}

class ImageModel extends BaseModel {
    displayImage() {}
}

class UserModel extends BaseModel {
    doSomething() {}
}

class DataService {
    repository: Repository = new Repository();
}

const service = new DataService();
service.repository.add<ImageModel>('image', new ImageModel());
service.repository.add<UserModel>('user', new UserModel());

const imageModel = <ImageModel>service.repository.get('image');
const userModel = <UserModel>service.repository.get('user');

imageModel.displayImage();
userModel.doSomething();
```

Right now, when getting a model from the repository I say for example that variable `imageModel` will be of type ImageModel, and that `userModel` will be of type UserModel. Is there a way to have the compiler know that it is of type ImageModel and UserModel respectively  without having to specify it while getting it from the repository? Possible by using generics and / or the infer keyword?

Comment: Is the name you added it under incidental to the type or are they correlated?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, so the name 'image' is cause it's the 'imageModel'. I had a typo where I also had 'image' for 'userModel' in the code. Fixed that now.

Comment: So, one cannot add an `ImageModel` under a different name, correct?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Well they can in this case, but that's not a requirement for it to work like this.

Comment: I don't think that's possible then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that in your repository, each type of model will only have one instance, then one possible way to simplify your code will be to use a `Map` and use the constructor functions as keys. As you can see from the example below, this could make your code a lot simpler and cleaner.

```
class Repository {
    items: Map<Function, BaseModel> = new Map();

    add<T extends BaseModel>(item: T) {
        this.items.set(item.constructor, item);
    }

    get<T extends BaseModel>(type: new () => T) {
        return this.items.get(type)! as T;
    }
}

class BaseModel {
    insert() { }
}

class ImageModel extends BaseModel {
    displayImage() { }
}

class UserModel extends BaseModel {
    doSomething() { }
}

class DataService {
    repository: Repository = new Repository();
}

const service = new DataService();
service.repository.add(new ImageModel()); // Now you don't need to specify anything here
service.repository.add(new UserModel());

const imageModel = service.repository.get(ImageModel); // As simple as it can possibly be
const userModel = service.repository.get(UserModel);

imageModel.displayImage(); // It works! TypeScript knows imageModel is an ImageModel
userModel.doSomething();
```

If you must use strings as keys to identify the models, and the keys may change, then I have to agree with Aluan Haddad that what you want is not possible. There's no way TypeScript could know which key referes to which type unless the correlation is fixed and you define the correlation somewhere in your code.